# PHP - condense array of latitude/longitude values into periphery values

Tags: php, arrays, maps

I want to convert array of between 2 to 1000 latitude/longitude points
(such as all postal codes in a city) into either:

- an array of lat/long values that represents the perimeter defined by the points
- an array of lat/long values that represents high concentration of points

I want to plot values on google maps, but want to avoid sending excessive amount of data to google maps.

Comment: I don't know of ready-made solutions for PHP, but have you looked at the various JavaScript-driven marker clustering solutions available for Google Maps?

Comment: I agree with Pekka. Take a look at this http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the perimeter you talk about you need the compute the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) of your points. There are plenty of algorithms available.

But I would suggest to use the marker clusterer library so that you users can zoom in to see all the points.